# Send Log4J 2.X events to Log4J 1.X

Tags: java, logging, log4j

We have been using Log4J 1.2.X for ever. Recently, we updated some third-party libraries which moved to Log4J 2.X. Now, we get warnings at the start of our applications; something like "No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration". We have a bunch of custom Log4J 1.X Appenders and Loggers. We have *no intention* of investing any time to upgrade those, along with literally millions of Java LOCs, to Log4J 2.X...

We *could* configure the Log4J 2.X to throw away all events, but it would be nicer if we could just pipe them into our Log4J 1.2.X configuration instead.

So, can we forward/bridge/adapt (with minimal work) Log4J 2.X events into Log4J 1.2.X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt log4j 2.x to slf4j by using [log4j-to-slf4j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j), and then bind slf4j to log4j 1.2.x by using [slf4j-log4j12](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12)

By the way, I'm curious about which 3rd-party library require log4j2, shouldn't they rely on logging framework such as slf4j or commons-logging? Require a end-point logging library such as log4j or log4j2 is really quite dumb and unfriendly.

Comment: Looks like we are already using "log4j-to-slf4j", so it's really the simplest solution. :) And after some research, we found the jars that need Log4J 2.X come from *another (independent) department" XD